# hystrix fallback methold not invoked when set up timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix

if set up `execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds` to be `20000`, and shut down the testing remote service: `http://localhost:8081/services`,
hystrix will throw exception

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://localhost:8081/services": Connection refused:
>   connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect

But what I excepted is the fallback method to be called, can someone tell me what is wrong?

**code**

```
@Component
public class hystrixServices {

private Random random = new Random();
public Logger loggers = Logger.getLogger(hystrixServices.class);
/**
 * 模拟获取用户信息(通过网络调用)
 * @return
 */
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallback",
        commandProperties = {
                    @HystrixProperty(name="execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value="10000")
                    }
)
//@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallback")
public String mockGetUserInfo(){
    try
    {
    int randomInt= random.nextInt(10) ;
    if(randomInt<8){ 
        customRestTemplate crt = new customRestTemplate();
        RestTemplate rt = crt.getcustomRestTemplate();
        loggers.info("start making the call");
        String result = rt.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/services", String.class);
        loggers.info("end making the call");
        //loggers.info(result);
        return result;
        //return "random < 8";
    }else{
        return "UserName:liaokailin;number:"+randomInt;
    }       
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        loggers.info(e.toString());
        return "point 1:" + e.toString();
    }
}

public String fallback(){
    return "some exception occur call fallback method.";
}

}
```

Comment: If you included Zuul into your micro-service architecture, you can refer to this article [Hystrix fallback with Zuul and Spring Boot](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/06/27/hystrix-fallback-with-zuul-and-spring-boot/) to enable fallback mechanism.

Comment: Very bad formatting, please put some effort into your questions.

Comment: thanks Maciej, i will be more editable next time

Comment: I found the timeout setting "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds" will affect how hystrix works. If exception happens before timeout setting limit, hystrix will throw exception instead of calling fallback method, it is the case?